# Injecting and asserting on helper classes and facades?

Tags: unit-testing, oop, testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a helper class `FooItem` that acts as a facade for another class `Foo`. I'm now creating another class `Bar` which internally uses `FooItem` to do its `Foo` related actions.

Since `FooItem` is a facade, my initial thought is to neither inject it in `Bar`, nor mock during testing, and instead, when testing `Bar`, assert against `Foo` directly. The idea is that `FooItem` is inconsequential to what `Bar` *should* be doing with `Foo`.

Is this approach better than injecting a `FooItem` into `Bar` and also asserting on its methods instead of `Foo`? It's tested itself, so technically asserting against it should be safe.

Some thoughts:

- If asserting on `FooItem` in `Bar`, if it breaks in the future, `Bar`'s tests will fail as collateral.
- Asserting on a facade or helper feels intuitively wrong since it feels most like an internal implementation detail that should be inconsequential to the actual goal target, which is communicating with `Foo`.
- In the future, if I use another utility instead of `FooItem` or directly act on `Foo` instead, the tests would be remain the same if I dont assert on `FooItem`.

This might actually be two separate discussions, one about injecting `FooItem` into `Bar` when instantiating it and another about asserting against `Foo` or `FooItem` in `Bar`'s tests.

Comment: If you want to avoid ibjecting `FooItem` into `Bar` when constructing it, how are you planning to pass the instance of `FooItem`? As per asserting, it depends really, if the code is straight forward and most of the calls are just delegated to `Foo`, I would go for the larger test.

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir I instantiate it in `Bar`'s constructor. `Bar`'s signature has parameters that are passed to `FooItem`'s constructor. After a bit of thinking, I think this saves having classes that instantiate `Bar`s having to instantiate `FooItem`s first since it's just a helper. Also thank you for your advice on the assertions. It is indeed a straightforward delegation, just appending strings then calling `Foo`'s methods.